# C# Adding an object to a listbox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I need help showing a specific string in a ListBox. The string comes from a TextBox and when you click the Create button the User's name is supposed to show in the ListBox. We add a new user like this `normalUsersListbox.Items.Add(new User(TextBoxNamn.Text, TextBoxEpost.Text));` The constructor takes two parameters for the Name and Email of the user. But in the Listbox we can only see that a user have been created, like this **Lab5.User**. How can we solve the problem?

Comment: Override `ToString` in `User`, for example: `public override string ToString()        { return this.Name;  }`

Comment: call `ToString()` like `normalUsersListbox.Items.Add(new User(TextBoxNamn.Text, TextBoxEpost.Text).ToString());`

Comment: Use a DataTemplate, or the DisplayMemberPath property of the ListBox or override ToString.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer how do I use the DataTemplate property correct?

Answer (score 1):

The Listbox calls the ToString()-Method for every Item. Just override the ToString()-Method of your added Item.

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
         return Name;         
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from overriding `ToString` you have a couple of slightly better options. You could for example use a `DataTemplate` (The `DataType` property can be omitted if you only have one type of items):

```xaml
xmlns:yourNameSpace="clr-namespace:Lab5"
```

```xaml
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type yourNameSpace:User}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Or simply set the `DisplayMemberPath`:

```xaml
<ListBox DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

If you need to keep track of your Users in code anyways, I'd also recommend using the `ItemsSource` property to assign users instead of adding them directly to the `Items` collection, e.g.:

```
// Declare this somewhere permanent
ObservableCollection<User> users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

users.Add(new User { Name = "Test1" });
users.Add(new User { Name = "Test2" });
users.Add(new User { Name = "Test3" });
normalUsersListbox.ItemsSource = users;
```

Next step would be to *bind* the `ItemsSource` to a `ViewModel` but I think that might be a bit too much for now :)